# How to share an Angular httpClient.get call using RxJS share operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can someone please help me with this problem?

I have a service which gets some data form a server with `httpClient.get()` call.

Also I have a component that uses this service and shows concrete info from this data.
The problem is that I need to have this component 3 or 4 times in the same page/view showing different concrete data from the same call and the component, due to the application architecture, must be whom makes the call.

How can I detect that the call already has been performed and reuse it?

I was thinking about the RxJS operators `share` or even `shareReplay` but in the explained scenario I don't know how to use it in a clear way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this article (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html) to have a complete description of caching strategies with rxjs

Comment: Already did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one `Http` request and work with cached/stored data. Use Below Approach

```
export class SharedService {

    private data$: Observable<User>;
    private getUser(): void {

        this.data$ = this.http
            .get<User>(BACKENDPATH).pipe(shareReplay(1));

    }

    getData(): Observable<User> {
        if (!this.data$) {
           this.getUser();
        }
        return this.data$;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach.

Comment: @pcasme Glad I could Help and dont forget to mark it if it was helpful

Comment: Sorry but my use case is a little bit more complex and althoug this approach is valid partially, I need to get cached calls to the same endpoint with different params. Any ideas?